How do I turn off the Intel "logo light" (not the RGB lights!) on my Intel CPU cooler?
I recently bought the parts for a new computer and put them together.
By default, its CPU cooler was making disco lights inside my computer until I finally figured out how to disable that nonsense. It was not documented anywhere; I had to figure out myself through experimentation that you have to first attach the special RGB cable to the motherboard, then click the button on that cable a couple of times. Only then does it stop the all-the-colours-of-the-rainbow light show. I have since removed the RGB cable from the motherboard.
However, there is one more light remaining, which doesn't ever turn off no matter how many times you click the RGB cable's button while it's connected to the motherboard. This is a white background light underneath the "Intel" logo on top of the cooler. I can still see this light from behind the computer every time I walk toward it when entering the room. It really bugs me. I'm essentially being forced to have bad taste. There is no reason for this shining light to exist inside my case besides to waste electricity.
I have looked through the BIOS settings. There is no related option there (not even to turn off the RGB lights). I have asked ChatGPT and searched online about turning it off. No results. The closest I find is about the RGB lights, which I've already figured out. Nobody mentions the lit Intel logo at all.
The CPU is a boxed "Intel Core I9 14900 LGA 1700" processor with the included, official cooler. I use Linux (if that matters).
Naturally, disconnecting the cooler entirely from the motherboard (from the CPU fan connector) will cause the CPU fan to stop spinning, so that's not an option.
How do I turn off the Intel logo light?
ls -l /sys/class/leds/ outputs:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 17 dec 17.52 input26::capslock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input26/input26::capslock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 17 dec 17.52 input26::compose -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input26/input26::compose
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 17 dec 17.52 input26::kana -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input26/input26::kana
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 17 dec 17.52 input26::numlock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input26/input26::numlock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 17 dec 17.52 input26::scrolllock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input26/input26::scrolllock


If the light can be driven from within an OS and if your Linux has the right driver then I expect there is something relevant in /sys/class/leds/. What is the output of ls -l /sys/class/leds/? Please [edit] and add this information to the question body (not in comments).

@KamilMaciorowski I added the command's output.

It's the Intel Laminar RH1 Cooler and the only hope I see for switching it off it to try more clicking of the button, although the "instructions" diagram 3B suggests that you don't need to attach the ARGB cable to use the button. Failing that, does it look like you could remove the part the light shines through without doing damage?

All your entries in /sys/class/leds/ are keyboard-related. If there is anything for Intel "logo light" then it's somewhere else (unlikely IMO) or nowhere at all. Frankly I don't know if the light in question can be driven from any OS at all, maybe not.

since the logo does not spin with the fan (according to videos) then failing a proper solution, black tape would work.

@Yorik The thought has crossed my mind, but I'm worried that it would cause a problem with the cooling or even a fire!

@AndrewMorton It may be that I got that part wrong from memory (since this was like last week or perhaps several weeks already -- time flies). That is, that you had to even have it detached for the button to do anything. It was un-intuitive either way. But clicking the button more times never did anything about the logo.

@user20986345 Black tape it is, then. Unless you feel adventurous enough to try disassembly via the logo piece to get to the LED to disable it, but then you'd probably want to have another cooler to hand in case it didn't work out well...
